# To prove a pertubation series converge

Tags: perturbation-theory

This is probably easy, however I can't figure out...  This is an introductory problem for C Bender's book.

The equation is $x^3 - (4 + \epsilon)x + 2 \epsilon = 0$.  By assuming the solution is in the format of $\sum a_n \epsilon^n$, and collect items of powers of $\epsilon$, we can work out the coefficients one by one.

Here are the equations I got:

$\epsilon^0: a_0^3 - 4a_0 = 0$

$\epsilon^1: 3a_0^2a_1 - 4a_1-4a_0 + 2 = 0$.

$\epsilon^n: \sum_{i+j+k = n}a_ia_ja_k - 4a_n -a_{n-1} = 0$.

Question:  How to show the series converge for $|\epsilon|<1$?

Comment: Hint: Your equation have  the constant solution $x(\varepsilon)=2$.

Comment: Thanks, I did realize that.  After dividing by x-2, I got slightly easier relations, but still can't prove the result.

Comment: You can solve your degree 2 equation, you get two solutions explicitely

Comment: It's possible to 'guess' the radius of convergence using numerical tests too.  Are you only interested in a strict proof or would a numerical approach satisfy you as well?